# facebook login using asp.net core

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core

I used this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins to follow steps how to make facebook login using asp.net core. I made all the steps, but the problem is that I can't find the code how to call facebook login api. All it shows how to setup all secret keys and so on... Final images shows the facebook button, but what action it calls they don't show.. could someone explain me?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET Identity you don't need to call Facebook login API manually. `FacebookMiddleware` does it for you after you add `UseFacebookAuthentication(FacebookOptions option)` code in the `Startup.Configure()` method. So basically you just need to provide `AppId` and `AppSecret` to the middleware and it will do the rest.

If you take a look in `Views/Account/Login.cshtml` you will see the following code which generates buttons for external providers:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <section>
        <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
        <hr />
        @{
            var loginProviders = SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes().ToList();
            if (loginProviders.Count == 0)
            {
                <div>
                    <p>
                        There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                        for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                    </p>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                            {
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.AuthenticationScheme" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.AuthenticationScheme</button>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            }
        }
    </section>
</div>
```

When user clicks on a button it will call `AccountController.ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)` action which makes a redirect to the external provider page.

Comment: So how should facebook button code look like in view that it would call fb middleware and now any other action?

Comment: Added more details to my answer.

Comment: That's odd... After doing all the steps from website, my app didn't generated button in view, didn't generated ExternalLogin action

Comment: @NikasŽalias did you add ASP.NET Identity to your project?

Comment: Yes I have added as.net core Identity

Comment: The code in my answer is what was generated automatically when create ASP.NET MVC project with Individual authentication. Such project already contains all identity-related code such as controllers, views, EF context, models and migrations. If you added ASP.NET Core manually you should have implemented all this manually. The other option is to create simple project by using command `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual` and copy the code you need in your project.

Comment: Here is the template code that's called by the button: https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/rel/1.0.5/src/Rules/StarterWeb/IndividualAuth/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L157